# VBA run time error 91 while exporting chart to ppt

Tags: excel, vba, charts, runtime-error, powerpoint

Below is part of a code that i am using to paste charts into ppt. It is basically picking charts from excel to update the existing ppt. I have also included inline text. where i am getting this error. Please help me identify, why this error is existing.
I am getting error at below line :-
m = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(existing_date_string).Characters.Start

```
Sub ChangeChartData_phast()
    
    
    Dim pptChart As Chart
    Dim pptChartData As ChartData
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wbk_copy As Workbook
    Dim wbk_paste As Worksheet
    Dim filepath As String

 filepath = ActivePresentation.Path
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wbk_copy = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath & "\development file.xlsm", True, False)
    'xlApp.Visible = True
    date_string = (wbk_copy.Worksheets("Data").Cells(13, 2))
    existing_date_string = (wbk_copy.Worksheets("Data").Cells(14, 2))
    wbk_copy.Close True
    Set xlApp = Nothing

 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wbk_copy = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath & "\Phast Charts Data.xlsx", True, False)
    xlApp.Visible = True
    
    Dim n As Integer

i = i + 1
        
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Name = "Title1" Then
                m = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(existing_date_string).Characters.Start
                          shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(m).InsertBefore (date_string)
                          shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(existing_date_string).Delete
            End If
        Next
Next n
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbk_copy.Close False
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Replace with a blank string or your text, instead of Delete

shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace FindWhat:="###", ReplaceWhat:=""

or try replace using vbNullString.